# How can I authenticate with credentials in the request parameters with spring-security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I am kind of new to Spring Boot and Spring Security.
I have a situation where I need a request to be authenticated and the username and password are in the request parameters like this `localhost:8080?username=bob&password=123` 
Can someone help me understand how I need to configure my security config, I am trying to do this as Java Config not XML. I also need to disable users trying to authenticate with basic HTTP authentication. So that the only way they can gain access is by providing a username and password in the request parameters. So far my config looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/test**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/pass**").permitAll();            

}
```

I am not sure how I can look for the credentials in the request parameters.

Comment: Do not use this approach because passwords are too exposed. At least, put them in request body and use HTTPS.

Comment: Do not disable csrf for your own safety because it guarantees that only requests that has csrf token which is generated by your application,and block other requests.  You can access detailed documentation from offical website. https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Comment: I do not have a choice on how the username and password are sent - as 3rd party company is sending them and wont change (even tho I do not like it either) and I do not believe I can use the csrf token because it is sort of an API like access and my application will never send anything back.